# SQL ANY as a function instead of an operator

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count users that match certain conditions. To do that I need to join some tables and check if any of the grouping combination match the condition.
The way I implemented that now is by having a nested select that counts original matches and then counting the rows that have at least one result.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(case when NestedCount1 > 0 then 1 else null end) as Count1,
    COUNT(case when NestedCount2 > 0 then 1 else null end) as Count2,
    COUNT(case when NestedCount3 > 0 then 1 else null end) as Count3
FROM
    (SELECT 
        COUNT(case when Type = 1 then 1 else null end) as NestedCount1,
        COUNT(case when Type = 2 then 1 else null end) as NestedCount2,
        COUNT(case when Type = 2 AND Condition = 1 then 1 else null end) as NestedCount3
    FROM [User]
        LEFT JOIN [UserGroup] ON [User].Id = [UserGroup].UserId
        LEFT JOIN [Group] ON [UserGroup].GroupId = [Group].Id
    GROUP BY [User].Id) nested
```

What irks me is that the counts from the nested select are only used to check existence. However since ANY in SQL is only an operator I cannot think of a cleaner way on how to rewrite this.

The query returns correct results as is.
I'm wondering if there is any way to rewrite this that would avoid having intermediate results that are only used to check existence condition?

Sample imput [User.csv](https://gist.github.com/Homulvas/c2b6a6ec400a6de444f1332d20254e08) [Group.csv](https://gist.github.com/Homulvas/d4624cbeacfae5b89736e5adcea9d7c3) [UserGroup.csv](https://gist.github.com/Homulvas/4d94ef11600399ca22af66ea72239b7a)

Expected results: 483, 272, 121

Comment: it would be great if you provide sample data as well as your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be possible to simplify that query.

I think that the group on the UserId can be avoided.
By using distinct conditional counts on the user id.

Then there's no need for a sub-query.

```
SELECT 
 COUNT(DISTINCT case when [User].[Type] = 1 then [User].Id end) as Count1,
 COUNT(DISTINCT case when [User].[Type] = 2 then [User].Id end) as Count2,
 COUNT(DISTINCT case when [User].[Type] = 2 AND Condition = 1 then [User].Id end) as Count3
FROM [User]
LEFT JOIN [UserGroup] ON [UserGroup].UserId = [User].Id 
LEFT JOIN [Group] ON [Group].Id = [UserGroup].GroupId;
```

Comment: I probably need to rephrase my question. My query is correct. However I'm not really satisfied with the way it looks and I hope there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
 SUM(case when NestedCount1 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count1,
 SUM(case when NestedCount2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count2,
 SUM(case when NestedCount3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count3
FROM
(
    SELECT 
     [User].Id,
     COUNT(case when Type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NestedCount1,
     COUNT(case when Type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as NestedCount2,
     COUNT(case when Type = 2 AND Condition = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as NestedCount3
    FROM [User]
    LEFT JOIN [UserGroup] ON [UserGroup].UserId = [User].Id 
    LEFT JOIN [Group] ON [Group].Id = [UserGroup].GroupId
    GROUP BY [User].Id
) nested
```

Comment: Hey Munish, try to add some explanation on why this code will solve OP's problem. Code only answers are not so constructive.